# AngularJS factory two way data binding

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular controller with some binded variables, and a factory that produces an array (used to populate options in a select control):

```
// Controller MyController
angular.module('users').controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'Authentication', 'MyFactory', 
    function($scope, Authentication, MyFactory) {
        $scope.user = Authentication.user;
        $scope.options = MyFactory.getOptions($scope.user.firstName, $scope.user.lastName);
        ...
    }
    ...
}

// Factory MyFactory
angular.module('users').factory('MyFactory', 
    function() {
        var _this = this;
        _this._data = {
            getOptions: function(firstName, lastName){
                return [
                    firstName + ' ' + lastName,
                    lastName  + ' ' + firstName
                    ...
                ];  
            }
        };
        return _this._data;
    }
);
```

It works well for the first time, but does not keep data in sync between the controller and the factory.

The intended effect is that a change in an argument of `MyFactory.getOptions()` modifies the resulting array assigned to `$scope.options`.

Comment: We can't find the bug, since you didn't post the real code having this bug.

Comment: Post definition of `getOptions`.

Comment: Its not really a bug, the code runs good, its more about the correct way of approching this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works the first time because you are calling a function which returns a new array, and then your view only ever references that array, and never calls the function again.  The easiest solution is to add a `$scope.$watch` for your `$scope.user` variable that recalls the `MyFactory.getOptions` function.

```
// Controller MyController
angular.module('users').controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'Authentication', 'MyFactory', 
    function($scope, Authentication, MyFactory) {
        $scope.user = Authentication.user;
        $scope.options = MyFactory.getOptions($scope.user.firstName, $scope.user.lastName);
        $scope.$watch("user", function(newVal,oldVal,scope) {
            scope.options = MyFactory.getOptions(newVal.firstName, newVal.lastName);
        });
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Something like that anyway.  Might have to play around with the syntax a bit.

---

Per your comments, try something like this:

```
// Controller MyController
angular.module('users').controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'Authentication', 'MyFactory', 
    function($scope, Authentication, MyFactory) {
        $scope.user = Authentication.user;
        $scope.options = MyFactory.getOptions($scope, "user");
        ...
    }
    ...
}

// Factory MyFactory
angular.module('users').factory('MyFactory', 
    function() {
        var _this = this;
        _this._data = {
            getOptions: function(scope, property){
                var updateableArray = [];
                function updateArray(user) {
                    //delete all elements of updateableArray
                    updateableArray.clear();
                    //add all the new elements of updateableArray from user argument
                    updateableArray.push(firstName + ' ' + lastName);
                    updateableArray.push(lastName  + ' ' + firstName);
                    ....
                }
                scope.$watch(property, function(newVal,oldVal,watchScope) {
                    updateArray(newVal);
                });
                updateArray(scope[property]);
                return updateableArray;  
            }
        };
        return _this._data;
    }
);
```

There is certainly a better way to organize it, but hopefully it's enough to help you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you, your approach works great! (there is just a missing 'true' argument after 'function(newVal...)'. The thing is, I would like to use that factory in mutiple controllers, might there be any way of changing the factory so there would be no need of adding that extra code in the controllers?

Comment: If you only update the properties of the user you can pass the whole user into the factory and add the watch in the factory that rebuilds the array.  Just be careful you remove the elements from the array and add the new ones back, trying to just replace the array with a new one won't work because the things you want to update will still have a reference to the old array.